# How to make a class able to access only certain private members of another class?

Tags: c++, class, friend

Suppose we have two classes:

```
class Base
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void f();
};

class Foo
{
    // some variables and methods
};
```

Now everyone can call `Base::f()`, but I want only `Foo` to be able to do so.

In order to achieve this effect, we can make `Base::f()` private and declare `Foo` as a friend:

```
class Base
{
private:
    int x;
    void f();
    friend Foo;
};
```

The problem with this approach is that `Foo` has the access to both `Base::f()` and `Base::x` (and even to any other private members of `Base`). But I want `Foo` to have access only to `Base::f()`.

Is there a way for a class (or a function) to grant an access only to certain private members of another class? Or maybe anyone could suggest a better approach to my problem?

**EDIT:**

I'll try to specify the access restriction I need. Firstly, `Base` is an interface in a library (it's an abstract class, in fact). The user uses only the classes derived from `Base`. `Base::f()` is called only by `Foo` which is another class in the library. Hiding `Base::f()` from the user is important, because only `Foo` knows when to call it. At the same time, `Foo` shouldn't mess up the other members of `Base`.

Comment: You could make `f()` protected and use protected inheritance I think.

Comment: But `Foo` is not derived from `Base`.

Comment: It was just a thought. You'd have to derive it. After seeing the `BaseData` answer, I'd go with that, though.

Comment: The access control mechanism in C++ is not designed for actually security it is designed to stop you from making accidental mistakes. One assumes that since you are writing both classes and as such can add friend then you will know only to call f() from Foo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very hacky, but this will allow very fine grained access.

```
class Base
{
private:
    int x;
    void f();
    friend class Base_f_Accessor;
};

class Base_f_Accessor
{
private:
    static void f(Base & b) { b.f(); }
    friend class Foo;
}

class Foo
{
    // some variables and methods
};
```

Comment: I like this approach, since it allows to hide the implementation details of `Base_f_Accessor` in a .cpp file. This way, `Foo` can also be defined in the .cpp file and not exposed to the user.

Answer (score 4):

You can create another class that contains the data for `Base` like this:

```
class BaseData {
protected:
    int x;
};

class Base : public BaseData {
    friend class Foo;
    void f ();
};
```

Now, `Foo` can access `f` as a method of `Base` like you wanted, but not `x`. Friendship is not commutative. By using `protected`, `x` appears private to everyone except those that derived directly from `BaseData`.

A better approach might be to use multiple inheritance to define `Base`, and provide `Foo` access only to those classes you want from which `Base` derives.

```
class With_f {
    friend class Foo;
protected:
    virtual void f () = 0;
};

class With_g {
protected:
    virtual void g () = 0;
};

class Base : public With_f, public With_g {
    int x;
    void f () {}
    void g () {}
};
```

Here, `Foo` would have to have a `With_f` pointer to `Base`, but it could then access the `f` method. `Foo` could not access `g`.

Comment: What would happen if you made `Base` a friend of `BaseData`? Would friends of `Base` be able to access it too? I think that would work better than inheritance if it works like that.

Comment: @chris: A friend of a friend is not a friend in C++.

Comment: Then that would probably do better than introducing inheritance.

Comment: @chris: Depends on what the programmer wants, I make no judgements on stylistic issues on SO.

Comment: This approach is also very useful. Unfortunately I can't accept more than one answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy, non-hackish way to achieve that. C++ simply doesn't have such access control granularity. You can play with some inheritance, but increased complexity outweighs any advantages this access restriction might have. Also, this approach doesn't scale - you can grant increased permissions only to one friend class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit cumbersome, but you could make nested classes where the nesting class is friend, then you can add friends per nested class.  This gives some level of granularity:

```
#include <iostream>

class Nesting
{
  friend class Foo;
  class Nested1
  {
    friend class Nesting;
  public:
    Nested1() : i(3) { }
  private:
    int i;
  } n1;
  class Nested2
  {
    friend class Nesting;
    friend class Foo;
  public:
    Nested2() : j(5) { }
  private:
    int j;
  } n2;
  int f() { return n1.i; }
};

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(Nesting& n1) : n(n1) { }
  int getJ() { return n.n2.j + n.f(); }
private:
  Nesting& n;
};

int main()
{
  Nesting n;
  Foo foo(n);
  std::cout << foo.getJ() << "\n";
}
```